# Effects of Social Networking websites on Humans?

Tags: social-psychology, internet, social-networks

What are the effects of social networking websites in the evolution of humans (behavioral, intellectual, etc.)?

Have their been any studies (published research, articles) on positive or negative effects of social networking websites such as Facebook, Twitter, etc. on human brain/social interaction among people / on kids or any aspect of human evolution?

Note: I have a computer science background.